# Django python escape \n characters

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

In the following function, i upload a file from a template and pass it to the following function.But the data gets crippled if there is a \n or \t(`This is a tab separated file`).

1.If there is a \n or some special characters it stores the data in the next row.How to avoid this .

2.data is not None or data != "" still stores a null value

```
def save_csv(csv_file,cnt):
 ret = 1
 arr = []
 try:
  flag = 0
  f = open(csv_file)
  for l in f:
     if flag == 0:
        flag += 1
        continue
     parts = l.split("\t")
     counter = 1
     if(len(parts) > 6):
        ret = 2
     else:
        taggeddata = Taggeddata()
        for data in parts:
           data = str(data.strip())
           if counter == 1 and (data is not None or data != ""):
              taggeddata.field1 = data
           elif counter == 2 and (data is not None or data != ""):
              taggeddata.field2 = data
           elif counter == 3 and (data is not None or data != ""):
              taggeddata.field3 = data
           elif counter == 4 and (data is not None or data != ""):
              taggeddata.field4 = data
           elif counter == 5 and (data is not None or data != ""):
              taggeddata.field5 = data
           elif counter == 6 and (data is not None or data != ""):
              taggeddata.field6 = data
           counter += 1
        taggeddata.content_id = cnt.id
        taggeddata.save()
        arr.append(taggeddata)
  return ret
except:
  write_exception("Error while processing data and storing")
```

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel, use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to deal with csv files, the module is able to handle proper escaping and other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the stdlib's csv module to parse your text, it will be much better at it.
2. Your expression `data is not None or data != ""` is always true, you meant `data is not None and data != ""`.  Note that you can simplify this to just `elif counter == 3 and data:`